# Angular 4+ Passing a String from one dialog box to another

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I have created a web application. Where the form name is requested to input when the "new " button is clicked and then when the save button is clicked the name should be shown at that dialog box. I have created the relevant services but the name is not shown. Here are the code segments

NewForm.component.ts

```
export class NewFormComponent  {

  public formName: String;

  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewFormComponent>,
    public formNewService: FormNewService ) { }

  discardSave(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close("Discarded");
  }


  sendFormName(): void {

    this.formNewService.sendFormName(this.formName);
    this.dialogRef.close();

  }
```

form-new.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormNewService {

  public FormName:String;
  public newFormSubject = new Subject<any>();
  public newNameFormSubject = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }

  get events$ () {
    return this.newFormSubject.asObservable();
  }

  get eventsName$ () {
    return this.newNameFormSubject.asObservable();
  }
  sendFormName(formInfo) {
    this.newFormSubject.next(formInfo);
    this.FormName=formInfo;
    this.getFormName(this.FormName);
    }

  getFormName(formname) {
      this.newNameFormSubject.next(formname);  

    }

}
```

saveForm.component.ts

```
export class SaveFormComponent implements OnInit{

  public formName: String;
  @Input() clickedNew: boolean;

  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SaveFormComponent>,
    public formDataService: FormDataService,
    public formNewService: FormNewService) { }

  discardSave(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close("Discarded");
  }

ngOnInit(){
  this.formNewService.eventsName$.forEach(eventNew => {
    console.log("dd");
  });

}

  saveFormName(): void {

    this.formDataService.getSaveFormName(this.formName);
    this.dialogRef.close();
}
  }
```

[image: I need to send the form name from New to save]

Comment: Can you show how you open the dialog? Check the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview), I think it's pretty straightforward to pass data in MatDialog.

Comment: @BonMacalindong the dialog box is opened from a separate component and it is opened just as it is in the documentation. i need to pass data from one dialog box to another.

Comment: So did you follow the documentation when passing data? `dialog.open(YourComponent, <your data>)`

Comment: Have you tried to debug it using the developers console in your browser?

Comment: The thing is that certain component does not have the form name. the menu component only have buttons which opens the dialog boxes. One dialog box get the form name and it should be sent in the okay click of that dialog box to another

Comment: @DaleBurrell yes. i did. The service is called but it does not get the response.  But the service is called on init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

You have issue with persistent of value `formName`. Your opted the service approach for communication among different component which is right however you are notifying the component instantly through the Observer. But the component (`modal`) has not yet appeared.

If you save `formName` through on `modal` and open the another `modal` since the notification is already been sent and this this modal which is new `Subscriber` will not be aware what had happened in the past.

### Solution

So fix this issue you can retain the last saved value in the service which you are already performing.

So just replace your `Subject` by `BehaviorSubject`.The `BehaviorSubject` has the characteristic that it stores the `current` value. This means that you can always directly get the last emitted value from the `BehaviorSubject`.

### form-new.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormNewService {

  public FormName:String;
  public newFormSubject = new Subject<any>();
  public newNameFormSubject = new BehaviorSubject();  // changed
  constructor() { }

  get events$ () {
    return this.newFormSubject.asObservable();
  }

  get eventsName$ () {
    return this.newNameFormSubject;  // changed
  }

  sendFormName(formInfo) {
    this.newFormSubject.next(formInfo);
    this.FormName=formInfo;
    this.getFormName(this.FormName);
    }

  getFormName(formname) {
      this.newNameFormSubject.next(formname);  

    }

}
```

> Note : You may need to change other `subject` as well if you have similar functionality for `newNameFormSubject`